# document.hasStorageAccess is not a function

Tags: javascript, storage

I'm trying to use [Storage Access API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage_Access_API) and I'm trying to call **hasStorageAccess()** method like this:

```
var promise = document.hasStorageAccess();
promise.then(
  function (hasAccess) {
    // Boolean hasAccess says whether the document has access or not.
  },
  function (reason) {
    // Promise was rejected for some reason.
  }
);
```

But I get an error that says:

TypeError: document.hasStorageAccess is not a function

Comment: Which Browser do you use?

Comment: **MDN =>** This is an experimental technology -Check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production. Unfortunately! Chrome did not made it to the list :(

Answer (score 2):

The Storage Access API is not available in all browsers yet. At this time, it is only available in Safari and Firefox, with differences in their implementations.

It's good practice to check for browser functionality before using it:

```
if (typeof document.hasStorageAccess === 'function'
    && typeof document.requestStorageAccess === 'function') {

    // safe to use Storage Access API
    var promise = document.hasStorageAccess();
    promise.then(
        function (hasAccess) {
            // Boolean hasAccess says whether the document has access or not.
        },
        function (reason) {
            // Promise was rejected for some reason.
        }
    );
}
```

You can check for browser functionality for 'hasStorageAccess' here:
https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_document_hasstorageaccess

I still suggest doing your own testing, though. I'm on Chrome 87 and the function is undefined. This is not consistent with 'Can I use...'.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the documentation you linked to, it says:

> This is an experimental technology
> Check the Browser compatibility table carefully before using this in production.

So it might not be supported by the browser you are using.

Would also not recommend using it, as most browsers dont support it.

Comment: _"Would also not recommend using it, as most browsers dont support it."_ [as of 2024, **all** browsers support it](https://caniuse.com/?search=hasStorageAccess).